# Material Themes Error - You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity

Tags: android, android-studio

I just started learning Android/Java and am reading through a book at the moment. The activity I'm on is pretty simple and explains the Live Cycle of an Activity and then explains how you can use Material Themes, showing how you change your code to do so. When I change the code (mainly add this `"android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material">"` and run it, I get:

```
 "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity."
```

I also get "Activity101 keeps stopping" on the AVD screen. As I'm starting I have no idea why this is or how to fix it.
I'm using Android Studio 3.2.1 and using a Nexus 5X API 25 AVD. Any help would be great.

Activity

```
package com.markusmartius.activity101;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    String tag = "Lifecycle Step";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d(tag, "In the onCreate() event");
}
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(tag, "In the onStart() event");
}
public void onRestart()
{
    super.onRestart();
    Log.d(tag, "In the onRestart() event");
}
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(tag, "In the onResume() event");
}
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(tag, "In the onPause() event");
}
public void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(tag, "In the onStop() event");
}
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(tag, "In the onDestroy() event");
}
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.markusmartius.activity101">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Error Log (please let me know if you need more)

```
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app    /com.markusmartius.activity101-1/lib/x86
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter      android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(andro id.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList,  android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the  package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.markusmartius.activity101, PID: 19455
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{com.markusmartius.activity101/com.markusmartius.activity101.Mai nActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a   Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
```

Comment: Like it says, you need to use `Theme.AppCompat`. If you want to use `Theme.Material`, you need to extend Activity and not AppCompatActivity.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I did see that originally and had tried changing AppCompatActivity to Activity, without success. But just has a revelation while reading over the code again and tried importing Activity as well, and found adding 'import android.app.Activity worked. Thanks again.